# How do I access properties of a more derived control class from a List<Control>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, controls, picturebox

I found that I can't use the `Image` property for a `PictureBox` control in `List<Control>`.

I want to do something like this:

```
    List<Control> pictureboxes = new List<Control>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var picturebox in pictureboxes)
        {
             picturebox.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.image;
        }
    }
```

Can I somehow do that?

Comment: Yes! you can. Do you have any problem?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that having to cast can often indicate a poor design, though with Forms the API can make it more difficult to avoid. Why use `List<Control>` if you only want to access `PictureBox`es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can't access the `Image` property of your `PictureBox` controls when you place them in a `List<Control>` container is because the base type of the list (`Control`) doesn't have an `Image` property.

The property didn't disappear, though. You just have to cast the object from a `Control` to a more derived class, `PictureBox`. Then you can call whatever methods or access whatever properties you want. For example:

```
List<Control> MyList = new List<Control>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in MyList)
    {
        // Try to cast the Control object to a PictureBox
        PictureBox picBox = ctrl as PictureBox;
        if (picBox != null)
        {
            picBox.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And with LINQ: `foreach (var pbox in myList.OfType<PictureBox>()) { pbox.Image = ... })`.